# Not able to access Tuleap SVN repo

Tags: svn, tuleap

i have installed tuleap, and created the project

when i tried to checkout repo from Tortoise SVN cleint it gives the error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

httpd error log says

```
[Thu Jul 09 09:40:52 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.199] PHP Notice:  DB error ==> SELECT content\n                FROM svn_immutable_tags_whitelist\n                WHERE group_id = 105 @@ /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/dao/include/DataAccessObject.class.php at line 95 in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/dao/include/DataAccessObject.class.php on line 155, referer: https://mydomian.com/svn/admin/?group_id=105
[Thu Jul 09 09:40:52 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.199] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRow() on a non-object in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/svn/immutable_tags/SVN_Immutable_Tags_Handler.php on line 34, referer: https://mydomian.com/svn/admin/?group_id=105
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some DB upgrades, please apply [Tuleap upgrade procedure](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/update.html#upgrade)